# Where is better to join data from few database tables? On Front-End or Back-End?

Tags: data-binding, frontend, backend

For example I have 3 tables and on frontend I need to show table with Users, their Positions and Departments.

I have the following tables in Database and can get it via REST API:

**Users**
id,
name,
position_id (foreign key),
department_id (foreign key)

**Positions**
id,
name

**Department**
id,
name

Is it better to join data to show in Users instead of position_id position name on Front-End during table generation or on Backend? What is the good practice?

I have Backend on PHP Laravel and Frontend on Vue.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the backend of course, because of two important reasons:

1. Network bandwidth
2. Data Security

you can write a query to fetch and combine the only needed data from those databases or provide [GraphQL API](https://graphql.org/) in the backend.